# Looking for a way to measure trail and error query alternatives

Tags: sql-server

I would like to tune my query but i found that i can not measure the execution time correctly because SQL is using cache and some other optimizations so every time i'm executing the same query i am getting a different statistics.

I would like to find a away to get the same statistics every time i'm executing the same query.

I tried to run the following before every execution but with no success (Every execution, different time):

```
DBCC FreeSystemCache 
DBCC FreeProcCache 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this (in test environment):

```
DBCC FreeProcCache;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
```

with combination of these:

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
```

Then, in the message tab of SQL Server Management Studio you will get these details:

[image]

In your case you are going to have many statistics and it can be too difficult to analyze. So, you can just copy the message tab details and past it [here](http://statisticsparser.com/), scroll down and at the end to analyze the totals:

[image]

You can see the totals for each object, so it is a good step to see where the most reads are performs. Since we are clearing the buffers, you will get the worst scenario when there are many `Physical Reads`- basically, this is a good start to analyze if a index is missing or there is something wrong with your query (for example, table variable or function is joined and not optimal execution plan is used).

Note, that you can get different executions time in the `SSMS` because of other activity on the SQL instance. You can use [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) to check in real time who is working on it, too. Also, if this is virtual machine and resources are shared you can get different execution time.

So, I would advice to clear the buffers and see where most reads are performed and check if they can be reduced.